# How to make an input format for coordinate?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to make an input for coordinate.

I use this script to add comma. But, it is adding comma every two char. I want it only add comma before the last two char.

```
$('.isCoor').on('keyup', function(){
    $(this).val(function(index, value) {
        var val_koor = value.replace(/\D/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{2})+(?!\d))/g, ",")
        return val_koor;
    });     
});
```

Comment: 1. non-greedy, 2. `$`. That's not a JS/jQuery question, but a regex one.

Comment: Comma? On Coordinate? Can you please show an example of such coordinate? You mean coordinate**s** like: `10.001, -20.002`?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan it's for a diagram

Comment: @Vahn did you find the answer helpful to you? You can upvote if it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a simple logic instead of using regular expression like this:

```js
$('.isCoor').on('keyup', function(){
    $(this).val(function(index, value) {
      var val_koor = value;
        if(value.length > 2){
          value = value.replace(/,/g,'');
          val_koor = value.substr(0,value.length-2)+ ',' + value.substr(value.length-2, value.length);
        }
        return val_koor;
    });     
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class='isCoor' type='text' />
```

Comment: This *works* so strangely oddly.... I'd never use this, probably neither would you, so there must be some better answer to this